# Most commands won't work on bash

Tags: macos, bash

So I updated to latest version of El Capitan (10.11.3) and adb stopped working for me. Upon messing with ~/.bash_profile, I made it worse and now most commands like `open` etc. won't work in terminal. I tried some solutions in other threads including removing the file, changing contents of bash_profile to mere defaults but it still won't work.

Upon executing `which` on `bash` and `open`, I get `/bin/bash` and `/usr/bin/open` respectively.

TIA!

Update: executing `echo $PATH` I get `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin`

Update 2: as asked, I'm getting a "command not found" error on executing some basic commands like `open` etc.

Comment: What does "won't work" mean here?  Are you getting an error message, and if so can you please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1033776/edit) your question to include those messages?

Comment: Also, what are "most commands"? Are you saying `ls` and `grep` don't work? What does `type -a open` show? And what does `type -a` give for the command you are trying to run with `open`?

Comment: Please check the edit.